# How to keep a socket.io connection alive

Tags: javascript, android, sockets

OK let's say I have a simple server set up like this:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var lobby = io.of('/lobby');

lobby.on("connection", function (socket) {
    console.log("Successful connection lobby");
    socket.on("disconnect", function () {
      console.log("Successful disconnect lobby");
    });
});
```

I have noticed that if a user just stays plugged into the system they are eventually dropped. I thought I could do something with the namespace, where I use a chron job, on a 5 minute interval, to do `lobby.emit('ping')` and all the clients connected would have an

```
.on('ping',  new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    lobby.emit('pong');
                }
            });
```

and the server would have a `.on('pong', function() {});` that effectively is a blank function. Is there another/better way to keep the system from timing out people who are not active?

Comment: This doesn't look like any Java I've ever seen.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Android, Java or Sockets. Tag it with SocketIO, because it's a protocol issue, not a client one

Comment: @GuillaumeImbert Except that that weird `Emitter.Listener` does maybe look like Android somehow?

Comment: The first code block is javascript. That's how SocketIO server counterpart is written. The second block is effectively Java code, on the Android SocketIO client app. Still, this has nothing to do with Android